# Rscript and e acute : encoding

Tags: r, encoding

I call a script named `main.R` with `Rscript`.

This `main.R` script contains these lines :

```
cat("first \U00E9 \n")
require("RStoolbox")
cat("first \U00E9 \n")
```

If I call it with Rscript, I get

```
first é
second Ú
```

The fact it that if I load a different package, it works. i tried with igraph, and it doesn't work either.

I put a getOption("encoding") and a Sys.getlocale() before and after, but nothing changes. Consequently, it's difficult to spot what is wrong.

```
cat("--before--\n")
cat("first \U00E9 \n")
cat(paste("encoding = ", getOption("encoding"), "\n"))
cat(paste("locale = ", Sys.getlocale(), "\n"))
require("RStoolbox")
cat("\n")
cat("--after--\n")
cat(paste("encoding = ", getOption("encoding"),"\n"))
cat(paste("locale = ", Sys.getlocale(), "\n"))
cat(" second \U00E9")
```

And I get :

```
--before--
first é
encoding =  native.enc
locale =  LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=
French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252
Le chargement a nécessité le package : RStoolbox
Message d'avis :
le package 'RStoolbox' a ÚtÚ compilÚ avec la version R 3.1.3

--after--
encoding =  native.enc
locale =  LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=
French_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252
 second Ú
```

Do you any way to fix this ?

Thanks in advance for your answers,

Mat

Comment: You can get encoding befor `source` and te set it again `a=getOption("encoding")
source("installAndLoadPackages.R")
options(encoding=a)`

Comment: I put getOption("encoding") before and after, and the same encoding named native.enc appears..I used your code but it doesn't change

Comment: May be while `source` locale changed? try to check it `Sys.getlocale(category = "LC_ALL") `

Comment: Before and after, it doesn't change. I get `[1] "LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252;LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252;LC_MONETARY=Frenc
h_France.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=French_France.1252"`. I noticed that 2 packages which are loaded change the encoding behaviour : RStoolbox and igraph. To resume all the tests, getOption("encoding") gives the same, also Sys.getlocale(). Difficult to see what's going on. Strange..